# In python datetime.microsecond omits leading zeros - potential bug

Tags: python, datetime

I have found what seems to be a little bug in the datetime package in Python 3.9.13.

I was working with `datetime.datetime.now().microsecond`, which should return the microsecond of the current time - it does so, but the value is returned as an integer.
This means that leading zeros of the value will be cropped, and the isolated value of the `.microsecond` will be flawed.

This is code in use. Here the full timestamp from `datetime.datetime.now().microsecond` is printed together with the re-combined timestamp from `datetime.datetime.now().year`, `.month`, `.day`, `.hour`, `.minute`, `.second` and `.microsecond`:

```
max_iter = 10
i = 0
temp_sec = None
while True:
    
    time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
    sec = time_now.second

    if sec % 1 == 0 and sec != temp_sec:
        i += 1
        print(time_now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
        print(time_now.year, time_now.month, time_now.day, '',
              (str(time_now.hour)+':'+str(time_now.minute)+
               ':'+str(time_now.second)+'.'
               +str(time_now.microsecond)) )
        print()
        
        temp_sec = sec

    if i > max_iter:
        break
    time.sleep(0.01)
```

```
Output:
>>> 2023-04-14 12:31:43.004813
>>> 2023 4 14  12:31:43.4813
...
```

This seems like a bug to me. Currently, I have made this work-around, which does fix my issue, but may not be the most computationally efficient:

```
def get_microsecond(time_as_string):
    '''
    Takes datetime.datetime.now() as a
    string and extracts microseconds as float.
    '''
    ms = str(time_as_string)[-7:]
    ms = '0'+ms
    return float(ms)

time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(time_now)
print(get_microsecond(time_now))
print(time_now.microsecond)
```

Are there other/better ways to get (only) the microseconds that I am not aware of?

Comment: That's nothing to do with the `datetime` module, it's your own `str(time_now.microsecond)` that drops the extra digits. How exactly would it return a _number_ with leading `0`s?

Comment: This is a bug in *your* code, not a bug in `datetime`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's easy to misunderstand your comment as saying that `str` drops digits from `time_now.microsecond`, which is simply an integer. As opposed to the formatted output of `strftime`, sure, we don't apply the formatting and we may lose zeros this way.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you could do

```
val = time_now.strftime("%f")
# type(val) == str
# example: ".046082"
```

or

```
val = time_now.microsecond / 10**6
# type(val) == float
# example: 0.046082
```

Both will be representations of the fractional part of seconds.

`datetime.microsecond` simply gives you the number of microseconds since the last full second. The fact that this doesn't include leading zeros is a characteristic of numbers, not a bug.